# How to delete node in firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello how can i delete the node in fire_base database using java ? 
i have tried this method but it didn't work.
This image show the node struct
[the node struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdi2q.png)

```
private void deleteTask (final String userName){

    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All_USER");
    reference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String userName = (String) ds.child("userName").getValue();
                reference.child(userName).setValue(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
}
```

Comment: What do you want to delete? Can you show structure of database?

Comment: @Yupi the database {
  "03THnBWdzFfuIwa3lKforsnxGNn2" : {
    "NewUser" : {
      "userName" : "1"
    }
  },
  "1RwiR0PV6CeY0au8YWGlWn4GsyK2" : {
    "NewUser" : {
      "userName" : "Sa"
    }
  },
  "8AJcjiHQbAODNEvmz1ygH2QP2J53" : {
    "NewUser" : {
      "userName" : "ma "
    }
  },
  "Ge7oiM52vvg8sMrAUnZqONcjBUD3" : {
    "NewUser" : {
      "userName" : "user"
    }
  }, i want to delete user which name is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is work for me

```
  private void deleteTask (final String userName){

    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All_USER");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(ds.child("NewUser").child("userName").getValue(String.class).equals(userName)){
                    ds.child("NewUser").child("userName").getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private void deleteTask (final String userName){

final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All_USER");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            ds.getRef().orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userName).removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }


   });
}
```

Comment: Than you have another child which you didn't added to your `DatabaseReference` path.

Comment: I have edited answer. By using POJO class when pushing data to database it is later on easily to manipulate with data.

Comment: this will delete all the node

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your code like this :

```
 @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                            snapshot.reference.removeValue()

                        }
                    }
    }
```